# Replacing text in String won't work

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to write a method that replaces some Variables of a html code in a String to e.g. the source of an image etc.

```
String html = "<img src='IMAGE_SOURCE' width='IMAGE_WIDTH' align='IMAGE_ALIGN";
```

Now that's my String I've written three methods for:

```
public void setImageSource(String src) {
  html.replace("IMAGE_SOURCE", "Here comes the source for the image");
}

public void setImageWidth(String width) {
  html.replace("IMAGE_SOURCE", "Here comes the width for the image");
}

public void setImageAlign(String align) {
  html.replace("IMAGE_SOURCE", "Here comes the align for the image");
}
```

The methods get called, but the String "html" won't change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your code like:

```
html = html.replace("IMAGE_SOURCE", "Here comes the width for the image");
```

Strings in Java are constant, that means you can't change a string's value, you need a new string to store the result of your operation

Comment: Yeah right, I have totally forgotten about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another potential problem I see:

You are using arguments called 'src', 'width', 'height', but you aren't using those variables in the functions. Do you mean to do something like:

```
String edited = src.replace("IMAGE_SOURCE", "Here comes the source for the image");
return edited;
```